# Syntax error in the representation of DCG in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, syntax-error, dcg

I am writing a grammar for a game simulation using DCG of prolog. I assume that the logic is correct by I get the following syntax errors .

```
program --> envsetup, commands. 
envsetup --> boardsize, obstacles, itinerary, character. 
boardsize --> xsize, ysize.
xsize --> "XSIZE", xysizenext.
xysizenext --> ':', integer, ';'.
ysize --> "YSIZE", xysizenext.
obstacles --> "OBSTACLE", coordinates, obs.
coordinates --> '[', integer , ',', integer , ']', ';'.
obs --> [obstacles].
character --> "CHARACTER", char.
itinerary --> start, end.
start --> "START", coordinates.
end --> "END", coordinates.
commands --> going, commands; turning, commands; changingspeed, commands; sensing, commands; printing, commands; stopping, commands; stat, commands.
going --> "GO", integer , ';', go.
go --> [going].
turning --> "TURN", direction, ';', turn.
turn --> [turning].
direction --> '(', "LEFT" ,')' ';' ; '(', "LEFT" ,')' ';'.
changingspeed --> "CHANGESPEED", '+'; '-', integer , ';', changingspeed.
sensing --> "SENSE", '(', integer,')',';' sense.
sense --> [sensing].
printing --> "PRINT", arguments.
arguments --> String, ';'; ',', arguments; integer ,  ';'; ','.
stopping --> "STOP".
stat --> "OKAY"; "ERROR".
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
ERROR: c:/users/its/desktop/dcggame.p:19:37: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: c:/users/its/desktop/dcggame.p:21:42: Syntax error: Operator expected
Warning: c:/users/its/desktop/dcggame.p:24:
        Singleton variables: [String]
Warning: c:/users/its/desktop/dcggame.p:24:
       Singleton variable in branch: String
```

What could possibly be the error?

Comment: you need to put double quotes in place of single quotes. So in place of `';'` rather write `";"`

Comment: I tried, but it did not work. Thank you

Comment: Oh, come on: read line 19: there are commas lacking, same is true for line 21.

Comment: Thank you very much. Any idea about the warnings?

Comment: Please look in detail, you really need to learn how to do that!

Comment: *Singleton variable* means you have a variable that isn't referenced anywhere else in the clause.

Comment: Found it. Good to learn from our mistakes. Thank you